# Unable to create multiple sheets using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to create multiple sheets based on the values in different rows in column 1 using openpyxl. The thing is when I run my script, it only just creates a new sheet using the first value and that's it.

***How can I create multiple sheets using different values available in "Sheet1"?***

My attempt so far:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Document.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for row in range(2, ws.max_row +1):
        if ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value==None:break
        keyword = ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value
        ws = wb.create_sheet(str(keyword)) #defining ws is a must here in order to reuse later
        print(keyword)
    wb.save('Document.xlsx')
```

These are the inputs available in `Sheet1` for creating three different sheets:

```
45824
33125
13958
```

Comment: What does this code print?

Comment: Nice to find you in the loop @Charlie Clark. It only prints `45824` and creates a sheet named `45824`.

Comment: So your logic is wrong. Once you create a new, empty worksheet this is where your subsequent loookups occur. Just create the sheet without assigning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `ws` variable and therefore creating a None value in `ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value`. Changing `ws = wb.create_sheet(str(keyword))` to `ws2 = wb.create_sheet(str(keyword))` solves your issue.

Comment: Looks very promising. Report back to you real soon @Frans. Thanks.